# angular__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__default.angular.module is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a angular/angularjs hybrid app

within a separate configs.ts module file I have below code

import angular from 'angular'
console.log(angular);

let configs=angular.module('configs',[]);
export(configs);

and my main.ts file has boiler plate hybrid manual bootstrap code.

my issues is the code compiles properly. however the imports angular does get instantiated by the console.log(angular); longs just a empty object

and subsequent line with angular.module app fails with module not a function/defined

any ideas. on the main.ts I have a separate app module that gets boostrapped